# use thinkpad tablet as second monitor with touchscreen?

Tags: monitors, thinkpad, touch-screen

i have an old thinkpad x200t with linux installed on it; for a long time i wasn't using it, but now i would like to use it as an additional monitor with a touchscreen for my current linux computer, in lieu of a digital drawing tablet

how would i do this? i see there are guides for connecting wacom tablets to a linux system, but in my case it's a complete computer rather than just a interface. as far as i can tell, all of the wifi-based screen sharers share the screen without allowing input. i suppose i need a physical connection, but i don't know where to connect it to or what converters i'll need to buy. and once i do that, what software should i install? is it even possible to do this?

thank you in advance!

note: my current computer has an hdmi port, while my thinkpad only has a vca port

edit: essentially what i'm looking to do is use one computer's mouse as input for another computer (with that computer's mouse and keyboard able to be used as well)

Comment: you don't get direct access to the display and touch hardware through external connectors – so physical connectons are not going to be of any use! What you need is software that runs on the tablet that displays what it gets sent (via network) on the tablet screen, and which sends what touch events happened. And the matching counter parts on the primary computer.

Comment: do you have any recommendations for such software?